# Concatenate strings in FrontBase SQL

Tags: sql, database

How do I concatenate two string columns in FrontBase SQL queries?

I tried what I thought to be was the standard SQL function:

```
concat(col1, col2)
```

But an error was raised:

```
 Semantic error 426. Referenced routine - concat - cannot be resolved.
```

Any ideas?

PS: Could somebody tag this as `FrontBase`, I don't seem to have rights for that (<1500 rep).

UPDATE: found the answer here

http://www.analysisandsolutions.com/presentations/portability/slides/concatenation.htm

I don't seem to be able to add Answers to my own question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [SQL92](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92), the double pipe serves as string concatenation operator:

```
'X' || 'Y' ==> 'XY'
```

(and AFAIK FrontBase is SQL92 compliant)

Comment: Thanks! I'd completely forgotten about that.

Comment: @Wouter Lievens, btw I've added the tag